# How to centerd 2 columns in a 3 column template

Tags: css, grid, multiple-columns

I have grid section that has a `grid-template-column` for 3 columns. But this content is loaded dynamically so it has 2 columns sometimes. I am trying to center the columns when there is only 2 columns

I checked the documentation of the grid CSS and tried a lot of different CSS but nothing seems to work as I would like to.

```
.wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
    display: grid;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.items {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Is using ```css flexbox``` an option instead of ```css grid```? I think thats a better usecase for this.

Comment: @ArnoTenkink sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the behavior you were expecting?
More about flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Addition styling */
.parent {
 padding: 30px;
 background: lightgrey;
 opacity: 0.8;
}

.child {
 padding: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 background: black;
 margin: 10px;
 color: white;
 max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Column</div>
  <div class="child">Column</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Column</div>
  <div class="child">Column</div>
  <div class="child">Column</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Column</div>
  <div class="child">Column</div>
  <div class="child">Column</div>
  <div class="child">Column</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
  grid-row-gap: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.grid-container div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The moment there is only 2 items the items won't center. They will stay aligned at the left

Comment: If you want dynamic then use js for this